# How to properly embed an HTML5 video player for schema.org use

Tags: html, html5-video, jwplayer, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am attempting to properly embed the JWplayer into a webpage and make use of schema.org. I already have the other parts of schema.org in place, i.e. thumbnail, duration, embed etc.

Is this sufficient or do I need to specify an embed type so that Google recognizes this area as my video content? If not, what would the proper code look like?

```
<object>     
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('playerManga').setup({
    file: 'http://storage.example.com/S/Samurai+7/Sam7(eps002).mp4',
    image: 'http://example.com/content/thumbs/Sam7eps001.jpeg',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9'
});
</script>
</object>
```

This is much easier when directly linking to the mp4 but using JWplayer is a little less clear cut for me.

Comment: Don't use an <object> tag around a JW Player embed - that's not how it works. Wouldn't you just enclose the entire player embed (its own <div> plus the <script> setup block) in an outer "schema" div, like <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">?

Comment: Yeah, no object tag needed.

Comment: Which schema.org type and property would you use if you’d directly link to the MP4?

Comment: Thanks a lot Neutron and Ethan I thought that the object tag was a requirement.Thanks for the clarification is the object tag ever necessary?

Comment: A simple example of JW6 embedding (without any schema.org stuff, however): http://misterneutron.com/JW6video/. No <video> tag, no <object> tag, no <embed> tag.